# convert date from rss feed

Tags: php

I am trying to format a date from an RSS feed using the following code:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $originalDate = trim($item->pubDate);
    $newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
    var_dump($newDate);
}
```

The format of the date is `Fri, 03 Aug 2012 13:08:11 UT` which comes from `$item->pubDate`. Unfortunately this code does not work and the result are `"31-12-1969"` How do I get the proper date?

Comment: Are you sure `$originalDate` has a value?

Comment: @Paul it has a list of dates when i use var_dump

Comment: `$item->pubDate` seems to be wrong. It should be `UTC` instead of `UT`!

Comment: ok thats odd the feed is from feedburner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't seem to need the time anyways, and just the date, this works for me:

```
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime(str_replace("UT", "", $originalDate)));
```

PHP doesn't seem to recognize the UT part.